# How to export selected functions, selected procedures, selected views and selected tables only from oracle database using command line?

Tags: oracle, export, impdp, expdp

Suppose I want to export

- Views named V1, V2
- Functions named f1, f2
- Procedures named p1, p2
- Tables named T1, T2
- username : system
- password : manager sid /
- schema : DB3

So I fire command on CMD as follow,

(1) expdp system/manager@DB3 directory=backupdir dumpfile=backup.dmp logfile=backup.log include=view:"IN ('V1','V2')", function:"IN ('f1','f2')", procedure:"IN ('p1','p2')", table:"IN ('T1','T2')"

(2) expdp system/manager@DB3 directory=backupdir dumpfile=backup.dmp logfile=backup.log include=view:"IN ('V1','V2')" include=function:"IN ('f1','f2')" include=procedure:"IN ('p1','p2')" include=table:"IN ('T1','T2')"

These both commands are not working:

> Error : ORA-39071: Value for INCLUDE is badly formed.

---

Following command works but it exports specified Tables only. It doesn't export views, procedures and functions.

(3) expdp system/manager@DB3 directory=backupdir dumpfile=backup.dmp logfile=backup.log include=view,procedure,function,table:"IN ('T1','T2')"

What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ORA-39071: Value for INCLUDE is badly formed

The command line doesn't like the quote marks. There are two ways to handle this.

The first is to escape the quotes:

```
expdp system/manager@DB3 directory=backupdir dumpfile=backup.dmp logfile=backup.log 
include=view:\"IN (\'V1\',\'V2\')\" include=function:\"IN (\'f1\',\'f2\')\" include=procedure:\"IN (\'p1\',\'p2\')\" include=table:\"IN (\'T1\',\'T2\')\"
```

If that seems tedious (and it is) the second option would be to define a parameter file. You can include all your options in that, without escaping the quotes, and just run `expdp` with the PARFILE parameter.

---

> There are no any changes in Schema 'DBpractice' in which I want to import the tables, views, functions and procedures that have been exported from schema named DB3.

That's really a new question, but the solution is straightforward enough: you need to run `impdp` with the REMAP_SCHEMA parameter which takes `source_schema:target_schema`. So in your case that would be

```
impdp system/manager directory=backupdir dumpfile=backup.dmp remap_schema=db3:DBpractice
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked after I created and granted permissions to directory. Now I want to export it to Oracle 10g.

C:\Users\Dell 7559>expdp system/manager@DB3 directory=backupdir dumpfile=backup.dmp logfile=backup.log include=table:\"in (\'STOCK\')\" version=10.2
********
All tables are being exported from Oracle-12c to Oracle-10g except one having definition as follow -->
create table stock(ModID varchar(20) primary key, Name varchar(30), Type varchar(15) ,mQty number, cmpID number, price number, Warranty number);
*********